# Registros duplicados, duda en la relación con las tablas de la base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos

En la realización de la siguiente base de datos tengo el problema me aparecen todos los registros de las tablas "operador" y "remolque", cuando por registro debe aparecer un solo operador y un solo remolque.Como deberían estar relacionada estas 2 tablas con la tabla transporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto parece mas un problema de la consulta que de la DB. porque pensas que es un problema de la DB? si esos registros son iguales, salvo por los campos remision y pedido

Comment: Añade la consulta que realizas para ver que es lo que te falta.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear llaves foraneas dentro de tu tabla transporte para mediante querys poder realizar consultas y de esta manera evitar datos duplicados y traer solo los relacionados.

Comment: entonces la relación seria a la inversa de como la tengo en las tablas.

Comment: Esta bien, necesitas en tu tabla transporte agregar dos campos los cuales serían: clave_o y clave_r. Estos serian FK de respectivas tablas. De esta manera cuando hagas un insert en la tabla transporte solo entrara un operador y un remorque.

Comment: Pero la tabla transporte solo se registran una sola vez seria una tabla padre, las otras 2 tablas es donde se ingresan mas datos. ya que un transporte puede tener muchos operadores y muchos remolques. un remolque y un operador pertenecen a un solo transporte.